# How can I get this information from a .txt-File?

Tags: powershell

I have a text file "C:\test\test.txt". There are 3 lines with 3 pieces of information. I'd like to get each of them into a variable.

This is how the text looks like:

> 14:30
>
> 1
>
> test

Comment: A screenshot of 3 short lines of text? Like, seriously? Anyway, what you're asking is certainly possible, but also most certainly not advisable. Better use a `key=value` format for the file, so you can process it into a hashtable via `ConvertFrom-StringData`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could import the file into a variable as an array with `Get-Content` and then use the [`[]` syntax](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-arrays.html) to define each variable.

```
$File = Get-Content C:\test\test.txt
$Time = $File[0]
$Number = $File[1]
$Text = $File[2]
```

Note that there are better ways to structure data for easier import.